# No longer able to access Data Source Details when creating an empty data view web part using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Using SharePoint Designer 2013 I can no longer access a list data source 
on SharePoint Online when building a DVWP

Steps to reproduce.

1. In SPD create a new Web Part Page.
2. Edit the new page in Advanced Mode.
3. Place cursor in ZoneTemplate tag.
4. Click Insert -> Data View -> Empty data view.
5. Place cursor in newly create DataSources tag.
6. Click Insert -> Data Source -> and select a list.
7. In the data source pane click refresh Data source link

error 
The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data 
from the data source. Check the format and content of your 
query and try again. If the problem persists, contact the server 
administrator

Ran a fiddler session.
get 500 response on.
/_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx.

soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.An error has occurred.

Also tried to refresh a data source on an existing DVWP with same result.

Anybody experiencing this issue?

Started within last week

I have cleared my SPD cache and tried on two different tenants.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue in my environment.

As a workaround, you can use Insert->Data View->select list to display list data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the confirmation of issue.
I need to be able to customise the XSLT.

I did as you said and selected a list to display.

I then placed cursor before ending last ZoneTemplate tag.
I then proceeded to insert an empty data view  as originally required
Click Insert -> Data View -> Empty data view.
Place cursor in newly create DataSources tag.
Click Insert -> Data Source -> and select a list.
The data source displayed and I was able to add columns and modify the XSLT
This should get me by as I can then remove unwanted markup and save the file